# UV Mapping Plane Single Side

Tags: image, uv

I have applied an image to a plane in blender using UV Mapping however I want the image only on one side of the plane not both. I am not sure where the setting is for this.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default or norm in Blender to have the texture appear on both sides. There is no *setting* to change this. This also doesn't need to be changed often as usually only one side of a model is showing.

The way I go around this to have the material appear only on **one side** is to use material nodes and have the base material on one side and a transparent material on the other.

*It is a bit tricky if you don't have any experience with material nodes but just follow the node layout and it should work*.

Just unwrap and texture as normal and setup your material and then add a second one, enable *Transparency*, set the *Alpha* to `0` and turn off the specularity.

As you can see below, both planes have textures but only one shows up when rendered. That is because I have added a transparent material to it along with the normal material and used the [*Geometry* node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Types/Input) to pass the materials to the different sides. One of the planes is on one side and the other is rotated `180` degrees around to the other side.

[image]

Here is the node setup for the material. <sup>*([larger image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr8k0.png))*</sup>

[image]

Comment: Can u explain how i add nodes and get it to how u have it

Comment: @BDGapps select the material and open the *Node* editor. Switch it to material and tick *Use nodes*. You add the different node types the same way you add meshes with the `Shift + A` menu.

Comment: "This also doesn't need to be changed often as usually only one side of a model is showing." Depending on the camera angle to the object, both sides can face, especially if the cube for instance has the top face cut out.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that single-sided texture mapping is supported in Blender out of the box. But consider this tutorial as a possible way to accomplish that: http://www.blendernerd.com/double-sided-materials/

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty: Make your image textured object 0 depth. So you have only a plane with an image on it. Create a second object with the real dimension and move the plane to the side you want the texture to. Join both.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Blender does not have a built-in setting for one-sided UV mapping. However, you can trick Blender into thinking that your plane has two distinct sides, which you can then UV unwrap independently.

To do this, add a *Solidify* modifier, set the 'Thickness' value to 0, and hit 'Apply'. Now, when you go to UV unwrap, you will have two sides to map, one of which you can set to an image and leave the other blank by arranging them in the UV/Image Editor.