# One side of an object appears normal but the other side is transparent

Tags: objects

I have Blender 2.49b and have this mesh:

Front:

[image: front side]

But on the back the mesh is transparent:

[image: back side]

How to fix this?

Comment: "I have Blender 2.49b" well there's your problem. Are you having trouble upgrading?

Comment: :D 2.49b Blender is good compatilible with export to DirectX for working in a game.. :D P.S. Its a not bug of Blender..

Comment: I don't know where this is in 2.49b, but try disabling "backface culling"

Comment: I finded it, but its only flip it [in front side is a transparent]

Comment: @GAMELASTER then you might have to make it have some thickness. (I don't know if 2.49b has the solidify modifier, but you might be able to just extrude it)

Comment: @GAMELASTER I have added an answer :)

BTW, related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/one-side-material

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 2.49b:

Try adding some thickness to your mesh.

It seems to be currently a 2 dimensional plane, which will only have one side drawn unless [*double sided faces*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Panels/Editing/Mesh) is enabled.

## 2.6x:

It seems that *double sided faces* was removed in 2.6x.
*Backface culling* can also cause this.
The *Backface culling* setting is located in *3D view > Properties panel > Display*:

[image]  [image]

Comment: In 2.5x Double Sided was moved to Mesh Properties under Normals. The backface culling option was added in 2.64 but the back of the poly should be visible in solid mode, it's only textured mode that hides the backface.

Comment: @sambler thanks :) fixed. (though backface culling does seem to effect the mesh in solid view?) According to [this](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21544&highlight=double+side), *double sided normals* is not the same as *double sided faces*

Comment: backface culling will make the back transparent in solid and textured mode(2.64+). 2.49 that GAMELASTER is using doesn't offer that so textured mode or texture solid should be the only time it is transparent.