# How to set different colors to each side of plane

Tags: materials

I'm making an animation of origami.

[image]

**[animation test](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-zmDB4Hxik&feature=youtube_gdata)**

It's not easy to understand overlapping portions.

I wanna set different colors to each side of paper.

Comment: I suggest you ask two individual questions instead of one. Although blender can render with double-sided material and wire material, I don't think they can be output and used in other render engine. It may depend on how WebGL renders it. So what do you really want to output, video or mesh/mat data?

Comment: Should be possible with GLSL.

Comment: WebGL can read JSON data of mesh made by Blender, so Blender has a [addon](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) to export the data. But I can't understand the structure of the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2082/599?

Comment: Double sided materials as well as Node Editor are perfectly supported in [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can do it by making it "physically" double-sided, which means:

1. In Edit mode, Select all faces, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to duplicate it, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) to flip normals for all faces.
2. Add a new material and assign to the selection.
3. Make sure to toggle **Normals** when exporting.

[image]

It would work if WebGL can do single-sided render (I bet it can), which is normal-based, like GLSL. Or you can make two separate objects that overlap each other, and have their face normals completetly flipped.

---

If you just want to render it in Blender, here is the solution for BI:

[image]

And for Cycles:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice!! I'm sorry late for reply. I understood your advice, but I couldn't success to display just a skeletal animation by WebGL on browser, so I couldn't try your advice. I will ask how to display a skeletal animation, and then I will try your advice!!