# texture is facing the wrong side of the mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

I am making a flower and when I unwrapped the petal the texture was on the wrong side. I tried rotating the mesh and flipping the normal's but nothing seems to work.

Here is the link for the [blend and the textures](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7ouokucenu0xx7w/AACvNP9-7V85q2S8BkLFg0ANa?dl=0)

Comment: Pack your texture please

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/how-to-set-different-colors-to-each-side-of-plane/6919#6919

Comment: Works for me.. Note that you've desaturated the texture where it's used in the translucent shader, making it appear black and white on one side in the .blend you uploaded. But the texture is still there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the texture is facing the camera...

[image]

One issue I did find is that you are mixing a transparent shader using an alpha channel, but your image has no such thing (jpeg images do not support alpha chanels), so that section of your node setup has no effect.

[image]

The backside of the petal is indeed colorless, but that is the effect of the hue saturation node affecting the traslucency (as @gandalf3 pointed out).

[image]

If you want to change the texture to the back of the object, add a **Geometry** node and use the backfacing information to control on which side the texture gets mapped...

[image]

**EDIT** 
(given that the question is so vague, the shared file linked to the different images, and the project layout open to so much interpretation...)

Is the error maybe that the UV mapping is upside down?

In the **UV/Image_Editor window** you can select the UV mapping and rotate it manually using the <kbd>R</kbd> key.

[image]

To rotate 180 degrees press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

To flip the UV mapping press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>