# Color Scheme node?

Tags: node-editor

I am designing a little something to be printed onto a T-Shirt.

But I haven't decided which color the shirt should have, which has direct impact onto the colors I want to print in.

Is it somehow possible to implement a Node where I can select between a few color schemes, eg. "Colors for white shirt", "Colors for red shirt" and so on, causing an "If selected first option, output red here and green here and..."

The thing I do not want is to have to fiddle with all the colors each time I change my mind about the shirt color.

Comment: Hello :). You could create different color variants as nodegroups, and switch between them inside one material :).

Comment: Hey :-) -- That would be necessary for every material, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Depends on how you implement it :). Related: [Switch node in Cycles material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74674/)

Comment: Just found this, could that be feasible? https://animation-nodes.com/

Comment: I don't work with animation-nodes but there are many experts on this site :).

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate a simple switch for two nodegroups.
[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74674/78972) covers a more complex switch with multiple inputs.

Using nodegroups inside other nodegroups could affect multiple materials at once.

[image]

Comment: IMHO It would be easier to create a number of differently colored models :).