# Apply same brightness to several texture atlas

Tags: texturing

I have two scenes obtained from Meshroom.
One scene is a big but coarse overview of the situation in the back of my garden and the other is a very detailed view of one of the objects in the scene.
I cut that object from the coarse scene and appended the detailed object into it.

So far so good...

Now I have the problem that the colors, especially the brightness does not match at all.
I'd like to apply more brightness to the appended object, but I figured that it contains several texture atlas png files to which I all would like to apply the same brightness.
When I use the shader editors node view, I'm only able to apply one brightness node to one texture atlas.
I'm looking for a way to apply the same brightness at the same time to all texture atlas pngs of my object, so that I can easily adjust its brightness as a whole.

Here is a screenshot of my situation which hopefully helps to understand my problem:

[image]

Thanks,
Maik

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Blender StackExchange! You might use a node-group, containing an rgb-curve, and append this node-group between each materials' texture- and principled-BSDF-Node. Like described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/global-variable-node-across-multiple-materials). Does that look like an applicable solution for you question?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the node-group. That definetly sounds like the way to go. I'll check it out. I'm curious if i can solve my litte color Problem this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node-group really did the trick. It was easier than anticipated and the result is very good. Even without any fine-tung, yet.

[image]

Maybe somebody has a good advice on how to better hide the cutting circle that is still quite visible in the scene?

Also, in one tutorial for node-groups, it was mentioned that I can change the name of the node-group in the "Item" tab. But unfortunately, there is no such tab in Blender version (3.1.2).

[image]

Any idea, where to give the node-group a reasonable name?

Thanks so far! It was a really great tip with the node-groups!

Comment: OK, I solved my little cutting issue with sculpting, using a little clay here and a little flatten there....