# Why does the math node change the noise texture's color output to B/W?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, color

Could someone please tell me why plugging a color into a math node (in this case set to subtract) makes the output black and white?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the math node only deals with single scalar values (note the gray sockets).
See [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33915/599)

If you use a node with yellow sockets (*Color > MixRGB*), it will maintain all the color channels:

[image]