# Create a light ray effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting

I've got a scene where a sun is shining through a couple of windows:
[image]
I want to make it so that there is a light ray effect between the windows and where the light hits, like this: [image]

Here's what my lighting setup is: [image]

[Link to the .BLEND](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EY1BjT3U1Qkw1MlU)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/create-light-rays-in-cycles?rq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/how-to-make-sunbeams-in-blender

Comment: Research volumetric lighting

Comment: @JoshSilveous  I don't know why the question has been marked as duplicate, given that the linked duplicates are not all the issues you are having. You can't do volumetric lights with a sun light (read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68668/volumetric-lighting-is-not-working/68671#68671) Then you need to modify the glass material so that light can actually travel through the glass material you have on the window. See:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/light-rays-through-glass/68426#68426 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/volumetric-spot-light-with-cycles/38833#38833

Comment: Then you have two choices to do volumetrics either add volume scattering as volume on the world, or enclose your object into a mesh that uses volume scattering. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49893/rendering-environment-pass-without-combined-pass-in-cycles/49923#49923

Comment: A very bright spot light, a simple cube around the scene with some volume scattering, a modified shader for the glass:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX41A.png

Comment: @cegaton You can do volumetric lighting with sun lamps, you just need to use a mesh volume, not world volumetrics.