# How can I avoid jagged edges?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

now it is last thing in my first project in blender. I made the model below in images and I thought everything is going well until I rendered it then I saw the quality is bad around the object that I built?
Is there any thing that I must do in render to have better result?
I will attach blender file to take a look.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe these'll help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/aliased-edge-around-light-source-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/how-to-save-an-image-without-antialiasing-in-cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compositing nodes are the cause. Because the blend does not have textures packed, I'm not 100% sure why you are compositing it the way you are.
However to fix the harsh edge around the container, simply check the *Anti-Aliasing* check box on both of the *ID Mask* nodes.
[image: ID Mask node]

Here is what the mask looks like Anti-Aliased on the left, and without Anti-Aliasing (how you have it now) no the right.
[image: ID Mask anti-aliased and unanti-aliased]

Comment: Hello David, sorry for coming late and thanks for your answer. I tried it today at work and I got a better result but it still not like the photo you provide here?! Did you done something else? Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Use a higher resolution. Maybe even use a "Dilate/Erode node" to blur the edges of the object. I'm not sure this will yield good results though.
Mainly, just use a higher resolution for the render.

Here's how I would blur the edges:
[image]

Set your Objects pass index to be a number( example: 2)
Then enable the Object Index pass in the passes tab. Render again.
Now put your object's mask (the first ID mask node) and pass it through a Dilate/ Erode node with these settings. Then subtract the original mask from this and you will have the edges of your model. Now put them through the blur node with the settings that you want.
I hope you get good results.

Comment: I did use a very high resolution in rendering but it is the same this is 3000 samples with over than 4000px. I did not understand what is the "Dilate/Erode node" if you can show an example please. Thanks

Comment: updated my reply

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I tried to use it in my file but I did not understand it really right I think! I am a new so it is hard to get it.