# White outline around renders when compositing in Photoshop

Tags: rendering

I'm pretty new to Blender so bare with me.

I'm making a GUI in Blender using Cycles.  Altho I have been doing my compositing in Blender, for the final composite, I'd like to export all the elements independently and do the final composite in Photoshop.

I am able to break out the elements by making the background plane a shadow catcher and rendering everything individually.  The issue I'm running into is there is a 1 pixel border of some alpha pixels around sections of the render that turn white when everything is put together.

I'm hoping there is a simple solution but I've been searching for days and can't seem to find an answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: Export as EXR? Are you using PNG?

Comment: Jagged edges can be fixed over the Photoshop Alpha channel or by using an ID Mask . https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73770/how-can-i-avoid-jagged-edges