# Some pixels doesn't render on the image ID MASK

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes

**LOOK FOR BOX TYPE IMAGES**

I need to annotate each SINGLE plant separately from others, for accurate annotation, right now I've it scripted for ID MASK. It gives each object from a specifically named collection iterated ID pass, renders original scene in .png, and then renders and converts pixels (every pixel, which is not black) from every ID MASK image to .json. But as you can see it doesn't works as expected. Is there something similar I could do with cryptomatte? Again, For annotation I need to know in advance which objects which color will use or something like that to know exactly or define an object. **maybe I can adjust emission shader or make my own so it can handle transparent textures correctly as well? or something along those lines** 
[image] 
**UPD** cryptomatte **works only** when I render plants separately from scene
**Look here cryptomatte whole scene vs cryptomatte plants only**
[image]
[image]

Blender doesn't render all pixels on distant objects, it gets better when I make resolution higher, like 4k, but it doesnt fixes my problem, but makes image pixels better. Also raising sample doesnt help. I tried to render with denoising and AA in compositor, that didnt help.
**How can I fix this, so it will render all object pixels on ID MASK using box pixel type?** I need an alpha of an object as an ID MASK, for accurate object annotation.

**Render Settings**

Engine: *Cycles*

Render Resolution: *1280x720*

Samples: *128*

Pixel type: *Blackman-Harris*

Pixel width: *0.01*

Full Image:
[image]
Problem:[image] [image]

**Additional info:** ID_MASK of the object in compositor
[image]

*Box* type pixels looks so much better on the Image, but **ID Mask dont recognize them**, now how to fix this one?

**Box type render:**
[image]
[image]
Box Type ID Mask:
[image]
**Box type Render 4k:**
[image]
[image]
Box type 4k ID MASK:
[image]

**Annotations**

Here's an [addon](https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv), which do almost what I needed, but it uses emission shader, which doesnt work with custom textures.

By annotation I mean assigning each pixel of the original (rendered) image a corresponding value of instanceId

Where instanceId maps a specific blender object.

[image]

Here's more examples:
Original Image without annotations:
[image]
Annotated Image:
[image]
[image]

**For now I just need objectId and categories.**

Right now I'm using ID masks which is the only reliable solution I've come up with.

As you can see I've tried a lot of other options such as:
Cryptomatte
Emission shader
Denoising
Playing with AlphaTreshold

Since ID masks don't work as reliable as I thought they would. I was thinking about writing my own shader that will use emission (to get the perfect color) and some magic to fix the transparent textures.

Here's why emission shader won't work in **any** case:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I know I should start a new question, but... **how to achive a solid color with nodes? If there's a way to get a fully opaque color w/o aa or any kind of transparency?** That would solve my problem perfectly.
Here's my node attempt:
[image]
[image]

**Cryptomatte did the job, but** it needs a manual nodes [pre-setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173144/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-add-objects-into-cryptomatte-node)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Increase the output resolution and you are done

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: You might need to provide your scene setting about those plants.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make ID mask to identify a pixel which is not the main sampled pass. Id mask only provide *yes, no, transparent* information, what you want is the alpha value of the solid color from that plant right? Did you try Cryptomatte?

Comment: I need to accurately annotate each plant on the scene. Yeh I tried cypromatte, but not with *Box* type, if that matters?@HikariTW updated answer with 4k box type

Comment: I will probably just render the plants without background, and use the image (alpha channel) as input to do what you want. Yeah, another scene required perhaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't use ID Masks

Just don't. They have little use, this is a really poorly designed feature. You simply cannot make a good mask with a 2bit color depth image.

## Cryptomatte is the solution

Look into using Cryptomatte. You need to enable it's layers in the View Layer properties tab:

[image]

You can then get any masks easily using Cryptomatte node in the compositor and they will be a lot higher quality:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue. Cryptomatte should provide masks as good as they get as far as I know. You can output them to files with File Output node and run any scripts you need for further image processing outside Blender. They can be saved in Multilayer EXR format and you can then open them in other software like in Photoshop with this free plugin: https://www.exr-io.com/. I have not tried it, but I think OpenEXR should also be quite a programming-friendly format if you need to process it programmatically. I might be mistaken, but it might be worth looking into it.

Comment: If you look in to the very first image of the question, you can see, that I'm already rendering masks in .exr. Please take a look at the **Problem** images, and at the **Box type render**. You can see that ID mask node doesnt cover those pixels rendered with box filter type, which I need to be also covered for accurate annotation

Comment: Also which way in your opinion would be best for annotation of 3D objects?

Comment: Just figured it out cryptomatte works fine, when I render **only plants**, but not when I render the whole scene

Comment: What do you mean by annotation? Could you give some example of how it needs to work in practice?

Comment: Sure, 1min, I'll let u know when Ill upload

Comment: Look at the bottom of the question, I've updated it

Comment: Cryptomatte otputs names of objects or materials with EXR format. I am not sure what software you use or how to make it work with it, but it [works with Photoshop](https://i.imgur.com/MBo8X3q.png) so it should be possible to get them from EXR programmatically. As for the mask picking up some background around anti-aliased(or should I say sampled) object, I think it is impossible to avoid unless the objects are rendered on transparent background and then the pixels contain only colors from the objects and nothing else since pixels usually contain color from multiple places.

Comment: Is there a way to isolate single object (single plant in my case) in compositor with cryptomatte ?

Comment: Sure, just set up the Cryptomatte node to output it's mask and then use File Output node to save the file during rendering. It's just a bit tedious because you then have to do everything manually - set everything up, name the file...

Comment: I'm getting a black image, could you show nodes setup pls? Using Photoshop with latest exr-io

Comment: [Sure](https://imgur.com/5vTVK8C)

Comment: Or better share a .blend file

Comment: Is there any way to automatically add object to Matte objects? Right now I have to use Pick output of Cryptomatte and then use eyedropper to add all the objects

Comment: Only Python scripting as far as I know. You can ask another question about that to get more help with that.

Comment: i've updated the question. could you please take a look?

Comment: Why didn't Cryptomatte work? I cannot imagine a situation where this complete solution for masking would not be better than ID masks in all ways possible. You are now asking for something that is impossible, because every pixel gets sampled many times and takes it's value from multiple locations, so an image cannot be masked with only black and white mask. Pixels around the edges of objects and materials just have values from a few different things and it is impossible to separate them once they are mixed, this is not the same as anti-aliasing in raster renders, you can't remove it.

Comment: I will test cryptomatte today a lot, and will tell you if it work

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason that you need to use `width : 0.01px` Blackman-Harris Filter? You are not sampling all area from that pixel but rather choose a very tiny dot to represent that pixel. [See this post for further description](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129636/how-does-anti-aliasing-work-in-cycles).

If you want all the pixel being equally sampled, use **box** or set the width to about 0.67 px width
[image]

Or just render the plants itself and use a math node to retrieve all pixel that have been rendered with color:
[image]

Comment: So **box** should fix the problem? I've already tried box, that didnt make any difference tho. Should I try box + higher res?

Comment: I'm not limited in using render settings, so any solution will be fine

Comment: @cxnt1 Can you provide the *box* rendered image? ID-Mask do a threshold control which does not support transparent(make sense)

Comment: WHat is treshold control? do you mean alpha treshold?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: You will have to increase the resolution of whole image. There are not pixels to show branches of your plant/grass. It happens when size of the object is smaller than available pixel to draw that object

Comment: So I should scale all objects to 1 or bigger?

Comment: @cxnt1 well, *lost protonbender* are not correctly talking the thing. If any ray cast on to the plant, that pixel will contain the plant no matter how big is that pixel. But when Blender need to choose a **main object** Blender will probably choose the Majority of the ray cast sample. And in your case, the dirt might be chosen. So you might need to separated them or maybe there is a better solution