# Is there anyway to match a sun lamp to the direction of the sun in an environment map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, light

I'm in the process of building a shadow catcher for a Cycles scene lit with a .jpg Environment Texture (equirectangular) - but it seems that the shadowpass will only work with a lamp in-scene.

I'd like my sun light to match the angle of the light from the Environment Texture. Can anybody think of a way to get the sun light angle from the Environment Texture without just eyeballing it?

--Rev

Comment: Do you know how sun clock works? You need to do the same thing: put a pole into the scene and measure the angle and distance of the shadow. Then you know where the sun is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the sun is clearly visible in the HDR, you can put a camera at scene origin, look around in rendered viewport mode and locate it.

If the sun is hard to locate precisely, you need to put a sun clock into the scene: put a vertical pole into the scene and measure the angle and distance of the shadow. Then you know where the sun is and how best to match the shadow.

[image: enter image description here1]

It will work for sunny HDRs with clear shadows the best. Also to get accurate shadows from HDR use environment setup [like this](http://adaptivesamples.com/2013/07/24/cif-2-hdr-lighting/).

---

For diffused shadow HDRs you will have to guess where the center of shadow is and how long it is, and substitude sun lamp for a point/spot lamp with some size. You can get the distance-size ratio from how the penumbra of the shadow looks:

[image]

Comment: If penumbra seems even, this ( http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage ) might help. Great answer, Jerryno!