# How do I make the shadow catcher show what's under it instead of the background colour?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

In the image below you can see a cube, a shadow catcher that is under the cube (Looks like a grey plain), and a red plain under the shadow catcher.

[image]

Right now the shadow catcher is catching the shadow, but everywhere that isn't a shadow, it shows the colour of the world background.

I want it to show the shadow, and then show the red plain underneath where it isn't catching the shadow.

Here is an example with an HDRI:

[image]

As you can see, the shadow catcher correctly catches the shadow, but it doesn't show the red plane underneath. I would like it to catch the shadow, and display whatever is underneath it.

I am using cycles with GPU, shadow catcher is ticked on the upper plane.

Comment: is that screenshot in render mode or viewport shading mode; or is it an actual render?  If it's in viewport shading mode, that's actually EEVEE and your shadowcatcher doesn't work as such.  If it's render mode or a render and you have Cycles set as the render engine, please check your visibility settings in object property and verify that Shadow Catcher hasn't come unset

Comment: Hi Marty, this is a rendered image. I am rendering in Cycles using GPU. Shadow Catcher is ticked in the object properties of the top plane.

My Goals is to get the shadow catcher to catch the shadow of the cube, but also show the red plane which is underneath.

What the shadow catcher is currently catching the shadow of the cube, but everywhere that the cube doesn't cast a shadow, the plane displays the 'world background'.

I have verified this by:
1. changing the brightness of the world.
2. making the world background transparent.
3. Using an HDRI.

Comment: Did you see this one? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70230/transparent-shadow-catcher-under-hdri-lighting-in-cycles?rq=1

Comment: Or this? https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/17/use-new-blender-shadow-catcher/