# Backface culling as a mesh property

Tags: python, mesh

Is there a way to mark a mesh (or a face in a mesh) in Blender as not visible from the backside, regardless of the view settings?

I'm creating meshes via the Python API, but if you know how to do it from the UI, let me know too.

This has to do with implementing the "solid" flag from the X3D standard.

Comment: Related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Answer (score 2):

In cycles you can use the backfacing information on the Geometry node to control a transparent shader.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's in Render view mode only, right? What about Material or Texture view?