# Is it possible to paint an object inside with one texture and outside with another?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, objects

I have a tooth model. I want it to be white outside and (any) voronoi texture inside.
Is it possible?

tooth model
[image]

tooth model with materials
[image]

How to ger rid of those [red things?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFbdg.jpg) They're caused by boolean modifier

Comment: how are we supposed to see the inside of your tooth, is it with a boolean?

Comment: @moonboots yessss

Comment: you've used image textures but didn't pack them, so the objects are pink, please reupload versions with packed images

Comment: How do I pack images in blender?

Comment: top horizontal menu on the left, File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend

Comment: ive updated file

Comment: a bit too heavy for my computer, maybe create a new question as it is a different question? but do you have a reason to have so many faces, why not much less faces and a Subsurf modifier?

Comment: So if I subdivide it my probnlem will be gone?

Comment: no I don't say that, I don't know what's your problem actually, as your file is too big for my weak computer   ;)

Comment: @moonboots I need a clean white tooth outside and voronoi inside. I need it to be placed on something to make it look more real, so I used a few planes with gum texture, and applied a boolean modifier on it, and now I'm having this problem with outside of the tooth, which shown on scrennshots

Answer (score 4):

So, as your question is equivocal, you have 2 possible situations: Either you're talking about an object that is open and you need to give 2 different materials to each side of the same face OR you're talking about the intersection of an object with its boolean object.

- Option 1: For an open mesh, use the *Geometry* > *Backfacing* node as you explain. Mix it in a *Mix* shader to separate 2 different shaders.

[image]

- Option 2, if you're talking about the face that is the intersection between your tooth and the object you'll use as boolean, you need to give your boolean object the material you want to see, and make sure that your tooth has both its natural material + the same material as its boolean object. Here, both the cube and the tooth have the orange material:

[image]

Comment: Backfacing solved my question

Comment: oh you're talking about the inner face AFTER applying the boolean?

Comment: does it matter if you apply boolean before or after? @moonboots

Comment: if you apply the boolean, my method won't work, what you were asking for was for an open mesh I guess?

Comment: What is open mesh?

Comment: I was asking about simple object

Comment: could you please show a screenshot of your teeth with the new material? it will make discussion more understandable

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TMUxzfX

Comment: If you know how to remove those red things from the teeth I'd be grateful

Comment: maybe share your object with the new material

Comment: its because of boolean, and I need to get rid of those red dots on teeth

Comment: Added file to question

Comment: I'm still having this issue  https://imgur.com/a/GHcyzHz

Answer (score 0):

Geometry node in shader editor solved my problem ([Texturing inside of model black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50759/texturing-inside-of-model-black?rq=1))

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that the normals face the opposite direction on the backfaces, so if you mixed shaders that have IOR for example(like the very popular Diffuse and Glossy mix controlled by Freshnel node), you would need to invert the IOR value(1/IOR) to get correct results.

Comment: How can I do that? @MartinZ

Comment: Like I said, just divide 1 by the IOR value you would normally enter for the part of the shader that is for the backfaces. So say you are making a plastic with Diffuse mixed with Glossy and controlled with Fresnel node and you enter 1.3 as the IOR, let's say you now wish to use the same mix for the backfaces and plug the result of it into your node setup to the bottom input of your mix node. The material will now look wrong. To fix it you need  to change the IOR value to 1 divided by it. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/Cw8MFiS.gif)

Comment: Please feel free to edit this into your answer if you find it useful or think this might be useful for whoever stumbles upon it in the future.

Comment: @MartinZ It didnt help

Comment: What do you mean? Is this not helpful in your situation, or was this still hard to understand? Did you see the link?

Comment: @MartinZ Not helpful, guess I did it correct?  https://imgur.com/a/kvScqMM

Comment: You have only diffuse shaders there. If you are using only diffuse shaders this is not needed so you do not have to do anything if Diffuse shaders are enough for you... I would recommend looking into using Fresnel in Blender though.

Comment: nah, doesnt work for me @MartinZ