# Add different textures to front and back of plane with solidify?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I have a map; a plane and a *Solidify* modifier. I have already applied an *Image Texture* to one side, but Blender is obviously applying the texture to both sides.

I want to add a different *Image Texture* to the other side of the plane, however. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to add another one using the *Geometry > Backfacing* feature, but it did not work.

*Map mesh and .blend file's material:*

[image]

*Viewport render of map mesh and Backfacing material (not working):*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Comment: The key piece of information you neglected to mention is that you are using a **solidify modifier**.

Comment: The reason backfacing doesn't work is that you have a solidify modifier The solidify modifier will make it so all of the object has an front surface (the bakface would be the interior faces of the object. If you want your map to have thickness  you need to apply the modifier and your plane will behave like a real object. Select the back faces and apply a new material to them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kCySk.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was only one image in the file, so I substituted a *Diffuse BSDF* for the second image. There are two options you have now.

### Option 1

The reason that the *Geometry > Backfacing* did not **appear** to work was because that the *Solidify* modifier made it so that the map/diffuse went inside the map.

*An exaggerated Solidify:*

[image]

The solution if you want to keep the *Solidify* modifier goes like this. Apply all modifiers. Use the steps in [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) to apply the other image/diffuse to the non-map faces.

### Option 2

*Solution produced with Option 2 (low-res; 20 samples):*

[image]

This is the better solution. Since the *Solidify* modifier does next to nothing, delete it, and the original node setup will work. The two *Diffuse BSDF's* outputs are crossed just because it needed to be inverted. I'm sure you understand.

[image]

The following .blend file produced the result at the top of *Option 2*.

[image]

Comment: Optionally you could also use the *Backfacing* output directly in a *Color Mix Node* to avoid having duplicate shaders

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Agreed. Are duplicate shaders bad, though?

Comment: Not bad per-se, just a slight optimization to make make the tree simpler, probably a few less seconds of render

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I've added a new image, after i applied these nodes, but its not working as you can see, both sides of the plane, when rolled up are same texture.

Comment: @Ulus can u share ur .blend file?

Comment: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/85006

Comment: @ShadyPuck Found a fix? :)

Comment: @Ulus I've been busy. Will try to get to it tonight.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Ok! :)

Comment: @Ulus Cannot see .blend. Please upload to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: @ShadyPuck Blender file at top now :)

Comment: @Ulus Finally got it!

Comment: @ShadyPuck The first option sounds a bit long and confusing, so I'l go for the 2. option because its true that the solidify doesn't make a big difference. Thanks.

Comment: @Ulus Glad that I could help.

Comment: @TheRageMachine et al: Solidify makes one small difference: it adds a bit of a highlight to the side of the paper, giving it a much more realistic look. I wonder if there is another way to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to use backfacing and solidify at the same time by checking the "Only Rim" option in the modifier.

[image: only rim checkbox image]

[image: node setup]

Comment: I upvoted since this worked for my case but it does not really solve the issue, as it only solidifies the rim.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solidify modifier, use the option *Materials > Material offset* to select a different material for the new face created by solidify. Make sure the second material is assigned to the object and it shows the texture you want. (I checked this on Blender 2.93)