# UV Mapping a box

Tags: mesh

I'm new to blender and would like to know if it is possible to do 2 different UV Mapping (inside and outside) an animated opening box in blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/add-different-textures-to-front-and-back-of-plane-with-solidify This might help.

Comment: Yes and No.... Anyway. Thx for your answer. This is for a plane, but seems to be different with a cubic box, and even more when  the lid of the box open & closes in 4 separate flaps ??

Answer (score 2):

would a setup like this fit your needs? here I used a simple cube, (top face removed for illustration purposes) and used the *Geometry > Backfacing* info to drive two different images on each side, using the same UV (you could even use two separate UV maps adding another UV map node)

[image]

Comment: Thx for the help.