# How to reverse normals of thick box

Tags: mesh, modifiers, normals

I am trying to create a box or room that has a slight thickness to the walls, with normals reversed on everything so you can always view the inside from the outside(with backface culling checked)

I have tried adding the solidify modifier to a box, then reversing the normals, but this doesn't work as expected. I then messed around with flipping normals manually by selecting the faces I want the normals flipped on, but this also didnt work.
What other method is there?
Thanks

Comment: Turn off the modifier viewport display

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Add different textures to front and back of plane with solidify](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/add-different-textures-to-front-and-back-of-plane-with-solidify)

Comment: You mean make the modifier no longer visible? I just tried. That might work fine in the blender editor, but I am trying to export to unity. So it needs to actually have all the normals facing the direction I want.

Comment: Thanks for the post cegaton. I dont know if its an exact duplicate, but checking "only  rim" like that thread recommended seemed to do the trick. I didnt see that during my  research

Comment: @Program232323 If you found a soulution, please write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. Other users who run into a similar situation can learn from your experience.

Comment: It says I wont be able to accept it for 2 days, Ill update it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check "Only Rim" within the solidify modifier. Make sure you also have "Flip normals" checked within the modifier as well.