# Softbody - opposite faces are bleeding through (clipping?) - how to avoid?

Tags: soft-body

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Learning blender, this is not a project of any sorts - just me learning.

I am trying to make a money bill, and I'd like it to have softbody physics, so that I can make a shower of bills flying around, landing on stuff.

I've created a  box and scaled it to the approx. dimensions of a bill: ie: paperthin. In the beginning I used the original dimensions, but I read somewhere that if objects are too small, softbody-simulations won't work that well, so I scaled it up quite a bit.

I've then added a photo of the to sides of the bill as a material using UVs.

BUT

When ever the bill collides with anything, the backside of the bill get's squished through the frontside. I have to make the bill very thick to avoid it - far too thick.

I even tried to use a lattice as the softbody object, and I've of course enabled self-clipping.

I've fiddled with the size of the virtual balls around each vertex, various combinations of stiffness and even damping etc ... No matter what I do, the backside ends up bleeding through the frontside.

Attached should be two screenshots, one just before the collision, and one just when it happens, you can see the backside bleeding through (with a brownish circular object) just underneath the tower on the right hand side.

How can I prevent the backside from bleeding through the frontside?

(Here's a link to my blendfile: https://filebin.net/m8t1i0xygrekchzp )

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39599/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-only-one-side-of-a-plane   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/add-different-textures-to-front-and-back-of-plane-with-solidify

Comment: Genious - a frontside and a backside for a plane: Yeah! This actually works for my goal!

Here's an img of my nodesetup (the imagetexture holds both the front and the backside of the bill) https://pasteboard.co/KWXHfENE0Mha.png

However I'd still like to know how to avoid the bleedthrough if using a box.

I'm not sure if I should mark this as the answer? It does not answer my question, however it helps me reach my goal in a different way.

Comment: Using solidify modifier will give thickness and avoid clipping.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try it with a cloth simulation?

So you could get something like this:

[image]

It's nearly all default settings.

Plane - resize - give collision modifier.

Default cube - give collision modifier.

Add two planes, resize to your needs, rotate a bit.

IMPORTANT: apply rotation + scale to all objects.

Subdivide your two planes a bit.
Give them a cloth modifier.
Check self collision.

Yes, it is not an answer for soft body, but money bills are physically nearer to cloth than soft bodies, i think.

Comment: I think you are using planes and not boxes in that example? But unfortunately I have the exact same problem with cloth :(

Thanks for the answer though!

https://i.ibb.co/8XCzNX8/bill-with-cloth.png

(photo of cloth bill with backside poking through frontside)

Comment: Ok, then please provide your blend file

Comment: here it is: https://filebin.net/m8t1i0xygrekchzp

Comment: The problem was solved further up: I am now using a single plane with a different front and backside: no bleedthrough (see comments for the original post).

It does not answer my question though - still it got me where I wanted to be!