# Is Backface culling possible in render mode?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

Let's say I have an 3D object (semitransparent) which contains another object in it. To make it more visible I used backface culling which really works fine in the solid display.
When I try to switch my view of the object from solid into rendered it seems like the backface-culling doesn't work in render mode.
Is it possible to keep backface-culling in rendered view?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Blender Internal, or Cycles render?

Comment: @ScottMilner just in Blender Render

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Select the material that you want to be with Backface Culling and enable *Use Shader Nodes*.

[image]

2. Open Node Editor and select the material you are using in the Material Node.
3. Add Geometry Node and connect **Front/Back** socket to Alpha socket in the Output Node.

[image]

Comment: For cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane/2083#2083

Comment: Thank you Denis! But my object should also be semitransparent / connected to the Alpha. For example there is another smaller spherical in this spherical. The bigger spherical should be semitransparent so I would be able to see the smaller one. How can I combine the two Alpha with the one at the Output?

Comment: @KhangCao I think it should work with math node using Add.

Comment: In Cycles: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2083/62466

Answer (score 2):

I saw that this was partially answered, but if you want to keep your existing alpha channel there's an extra step. Create a Math node and connect the Alpha socket from the Material node to one of the two sockets, and the Front/Back socket from the Geometry node to the other. Be sure to set it to Multiply, not Add like the existing comment said.
[image: Nodes]