# How to only render shaders on one side of an object

Tags: shaders

I was watching a youtube video about level design.  It spoke about only showing shaders visible to the player such as the inside of a room but not the outside for performance reasons.  How do you make the inside visible and the outside transparent?

Comment: Sounds like you want backface culling. The answer in this thread might be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72165/is-backface-culling-possible-in-render-mode

Comment: That is an intrinsic shader property dependent on the specific rendering engine you will use, which you never mention. Unless you use BGE, it is not something you would do directly inside Blender, and hence off topic here. That is most likely done by default anyway. For Blender Internal/ BGE see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/striped-sphere-hide-backfaces/59073#59073