# How to hide a mesh on render, but keep hiding polygon it was hiding?

Tags: rendering

I'm using blender to render sprites for a game.
I have a character mesh, and a T-Shirt mesh, rendered with a transparent background.
[image]

I want to render the T-Shirt without the character, disabling the character I get this:
[image]

How to make the polygons that were hidden by the character transparent?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72165/is-backface-culling-possible-in-render-mode) and [for cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane/2083#2083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the pass index of the shirt to 1 (material tab>settings>pass index). Enable material index for the render layer (render layers tab>passes>material index). Go into the compositor (top bar where it says default, change it to compositing). Select use nodes and set up this node setup:[image]

For the top image input on the Alpha Over node set A: to 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm trying to make the same operation as described here... All is fine, the only problem I'm having is that I can't get rid of the white background.

Comment: @Outandil See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/12