# Restrict HDRI Lighting to affecting certain places

Tags: lighting, hdri

I have a small question. I was trying to get the hdri lighting only through the windows. As you can see, my model has one side of its face open and I don't want the hdri lighting to affect the open side, I want the lighting only from the Windows. The only way I can stop the lighting from affecting the model is to create two opaque planes along it, but I need to be able to see the inside of it without having the hdri lighting affecting it. How can I do it ?[image]

Comment: I flipped the normals and used backface culling but it only works in the solid/material view, doesn't work in the render view mode.

Comment: Quite objviously that backface culling works only in viewport. It wasn't clear from your question do you want light from the world to be blocked only when in viewport or for render as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, For Cycles this node setup using the geometry node is to be used for making the object transparent on one side and completely opaque/diffused on the other, flipping the normals will help switch the sides and determine which side has which shader[image]

Comment: Here's a link to the original question     https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane/2083#2083

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not using an HDRI, just use a plane with an emit shader,

To the question at hand, you can place planes to block light and then hide them by pressing H, alternatively you can set the display mode to wire, that way it will still be opaque at render time but not in  viewport.

[image: this option here]

additionally I'd recommend using a portal on the window to better performance.

At the moment that scene will be very heavy to render and you won't be reaping much benefit from an HDRI, just a warning, if your PC can handle it no problem.

Comment: I tried using planes to block the light but hiding them also hides them in the render and the light still comes through.

Comment: You can set the display mode to wire as an alternative to hiding, that way you leave it unhidden, and in render it will be opaque.

This is assuming you want to render with a camera inside the room which I'm now thinking is not the case right?