# Outline that follows character?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I downloaded an anime model off of the internet and it has this really cool outline effect that follows the rotation of the character.

[image: Angle 1]
[image: Angle 2]
[image: Angle 3]

As you can see, it has an outline that constantly follows the character's rotation. This is a really awesome effect that I want to learn, but I have absolutely no clue how I could. Does anyone know what it is and/or how I can do it?

Comment: As you downloaded that file so you can investigate it. One most likely way is that author of the file wisely used Freestyle render engine which in Blender internal works even on viewport render (Shift+Z). Freestyle config probably is done not only in Scene tab in Properties but also in Texture nodes > Freestyle tree.

Comment: U mean freestyle?

Comment: @Leo yeah turns out thats what its called

Answer (score 5):

You can get an outline in the viewport with a simple hack that involves a solidify modifier and a second black material.
[image]

The image contains all the setup you need. To summarize, what we are doing is:

- Add a second material to the mesh you want to have the outline one, set color to black.
- Add a solidify modifier with the above settings, which creates an inverted normal shell around the original mesh. Assign it the outline material using Material Index Offset.
- Turn on 'Backface Culling' in the viewport so that the backface of the black outline is not visible.
- To make this setup work in Blender Render and Cycles, check this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane).