# Texture on inside of mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, image

Ive added an image texture to this object and the texture shows all over, which is fine however I wanted to create another texture image (of rust) on the INSIDE this time... how would I go about doing that in the nodes as the outside faces are the same as the inside ones so I cant select them and just create a new material

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: Use a geometry>backfacing node. Read: [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane/2085#2085)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solidify modifier to essentially add a second copy of the object on the inside. Select the inside geometry and assign it to one material, and the outside geometry to another material. Then they can be textured differently!