# How to assign color/texture only inside of cylinder?

Tags: materials, color

[image: example]

When I try to select faces only inside and assign color it selects and paints the outside part too(blue in the example). Any way to select only the inside faces of the cylinder?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane . Maybe it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane)