# How can I paint the uv only on the outside?

Tags: uv

[image]

I'd like a different color for the inside.
I want to make a pumpkin with a uv shell on the outside and just orange on the inside.
it is possible?

Comment: Use the Geometry node as a factor between the inner and the outer materials: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Comment: tahnk you very much

Comment: Note that if you want to export it to a game engine for instance, you would have to create additional geometry with its normals faced inside else it would be automatically culled from view

Comment: ok thank you for explanation! :)