# Is a "ray-destroying" material possible?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a hole like this:
[image]

I want only the "positive side" of the hole to be visible. Backface culling seemed promising, but I also need to hide the geometry behind the backfaces...

[image]

My idea was to give the backface some material that would tell the renderer "dont render me and anything behind me"  - effectively a ray-destroying material. Is this possible? Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I think that it's not exactly what he wants, he wants to be able to see through the object itself

Comment: @Vojta Šára, You can mix a Holdout with a Diffuse (or whatever) into a Mix Shader and use a Geometry (Backface output) as factor

Comment: in Eevee don't forget to set the Material > Settings > Blender mode to Alpha Blend and disable Show Backface