# How to apply a texture on one side but not on the same side?

Tags: texturing

I want to apply a dark color inside and leave the color as it is, outside how to do

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can use the Input > Geometry node > Backfacing output as a factor in a Mix Shader between 2 different shaders

Comment: Your bottom image appears to show that you have seperate faces for the outside and inside of your object, in which case just select the face on the side you need the texture on, select (or add) the texture from your list on the texture panel and click Assign.

Comment: No they are the same I assure you I just made a double-sided effect for the entrance and the exit, but after, it's all flat

Comment: @moonboots do you have a video tutorial please :/ ?

Comment: Here is the setup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Comment: Parfait merci beaucoup !