# 2 different textures are overlaying (Blender Render)

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

My goal is to model an object with 2 different textures(one from each side).

I have an original object that represents the external side (normals pointing to the outside). I then duplicated it and flipped the normals(so it represents the internal side). I also unchecked the checkbox 'Double Sided' in the Object Data.

Can anyone please help me to remove the overlaying texture?

[image]

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Using 2 different textures for a single one sided polygon is pissible via nodes only. I think you need to read about Geometry node a bit.

Comment: Related, [UV Mapping Plane Single Side](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1032/12).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were correct in adding geometry. However, when vertices/faces share the exact same space in Blender, you will get artifacts that are drawn all of the mesh.

To fix this, simply adjust the geometry so it doesn't share the same space. You can scale it in (with <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) or delete the inside geometry, add a solidify modifier and set the material index offset to the material index of the inside material:

[image]

*(The material index is zero-based. Thus, the selected materials index is 1)*

[image]

*(Set the material index to 1)*

Result:

[image]

*(Object cut in half for demonstration purposes)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! The object i will be working on is more complex than the one i put here. So a scale would cause a problem, but the solidify modifier worked perfectly. Thank you!